# resolving a dns entry for a virtual machine from physical host

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have a Win server 2k8r2 installed on a VmWare VM. This is confgiured as a domain controller and has a DNS server. I have an A-record created that I use for a sample test web site hosted in IIS.
say http://mytestsitename.mydomain.com where mytestsitename is the A-record. The physical host is running Win 7 Ultimate. The host and VM are on different subnets. I can ping the VM from the host using the VM machine name but cannot hit the FQDN of the Vm or the site above.

Is there a way to achieve this (use the VM's DNS server?) so that I can resolve the site / VM using FQDN from the physical host.

Thanks.

Comment: If you downvote a question, please leave a reason in the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Set the physical host to use the VM for name resolution.

Comment: Where would you set this up? I tried using the the "Preferred DNS Server" section of the TCP/IP v4 properties dialog of the VMWare virtual network adapter settings for the host and then tried to ping the <machinename>.<domainname>.com but no joy

Comment: Don't set it on the virtual adapter. Set it on the actual adapter that you have traffic flowing on.

Comment: Would that be set up as the Alternate DNS on the primary? I still need the DNS from my ISP for name resolution for external sites

Comment: If you set up recursion on your VM properly, you will still be able to resolve external sites, so set it as the primary. I assume this is just for a test lab and not a production environment. If this is in production, you've made some poor design decisions.

Comment: This is just for a home test lab environment, and as you can tell I'm a noob in networking. I'm not so concerned about not being able to resolve external sites from the VM as much as from the physical host and hence the question about where would I need to specify the DNS server address.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I had to set the DNS server in the VM ware virtual adapter. I had the wrong address for the DNS server so the pings were not going across. It works now. Thanks a bunch for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing if the host is in another domain, or relies on DNS for something else; I'd say your easiest solution would be to add an entry to the hosts file of the host machine.

Comment: the host is on a workgroup and the VM is on a domain. The Ip subnets are different. I can ping the VM machine name from the host but i can't ping the FQDN